# Company has not processed ACH payment

Tags: ach

I recently bought a car that I paid for using an ACH over 3 months ago. Yet, the money has still not left my account. Could it be that they just forgot to accept the payment? I have been in touch with them up to last month but neither of us has mentioned a payment issue. In my eyes, it should be their responsibility to follow through if they haven't been paid. What is the expiration for something like this? Maybe I just put the money aside into an account to gain interest?

Comment: ACH is not the same as a wire transfer, as far as I can tell.

Comment: It was likely an ACH. I've updated question.

Comment: "Maybe I just put the money aside into an account to gain interest?" I would keep it in the account to make sure you don't get overdrafted if they ever find the mistake. The minute interest is not worth the risk.

Comment: i have seen delays in ACH charging of up to 15 days, as they don’t seem to be in a hurry. Even my monthly mortgage ACH is sometimes 5 or 6 days late, so that is normal. should the payment have started three months ago? or just this month?

Comment: "_but neither of us has mentioned a payment issue_" Your best course probably _is_ to mention the issue and get it cleared-up as soon as possible, so you _don't_ need to leave money set-aside. After all, you've got the car so you owe them some money, and a clerical error on their part or the bank doesn't alter that.